# string split and validation using apache freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I have a text like this `"please list TK 3-ASDFGVB"`.

I need to validate this text using freemarker with following scenarios:

- In text make sure, after TK "3-ASDFGVB" should present.
- "3-ASDFGVB" should contain total 9 character.
- "3-ASDFGVB" make sure "-" present between 3 and ASDFGVB

Tried the scenario's with below code.

```
TKNumberstr="please list TK 3-ASDFGVB"

{TKNumberstr.value?matches('.*([0-3]-[0-9]{9}).*')?then('match','nomatch')}
```

All I want to do it single line which is mentioned in the above. If the validation match then I will continue with next process. Need help to validate the rule.

Comment: Do you need help writing the regex itself or help executing the test? Also what's your application built with (Spring MVC, Spring Boot, ... etc)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Based on the info you provided it looks like that TKNumberstr is a string. If thats the case you shouldn't use .value.
2. the regex *.*([0-3]-[0-9]{9}).** does not verify the scenarios you described. I recomend you adding the regex tag on your question.

Check if this helps you:

```
[#assign TKNumberstr="please list TK 3-ASDFGVB" /]
${TKNumberstr?matches('.*([0-3]-[A-Z]{7}).*')?then('match','nomatch')}
```

Note that I changed **[0-9]{9}** to **[A-Z]{7}** since the {number} does not include the **[0-3]-** part and what comes after  the - in your example are uppercase letters.

If that doesn't help you please let us know the error message you get.